# How can I fit more dishes in my microwave at once?

Tags: food, appliances, organization

I have a 0.6 cubic foot rotating microwave (very small), so I can usually only cook one thing at a time. When using bowls I tried to put them both in opposite corners and they both fit, but one tipped over because of the rotating circle in the middle of the microwave and spilled everywhere.

Is there any way that I can fit two bowls (or plates) in the same microwave without either one getting in the way of the other one?

Comment: Do you have a rotating microwave? How large is it? More details would likely give you better answers. As it is your question is relatively unclear

Comment: @ZachSaucier Edited the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a microwave safe mug or cup to elevate one of the bowls or plates.

[image: Life Hack]

<sup>Image from [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/354236326917043974/)</sup>

This works much better with bowls because plates will slip and slide more.

Answer (score 5):

Any of these will work:

- Disable the turntable (when it's on, you're essentially cropping the rectangular footprint into a smaller, circular one)
- Elevate one item with a microwave-safe mug, making sure the bowl/plate is *well-supported*

Also note that microwaving multiple items at once saves no time ([You have to approximately double cooking time for two](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/27749/30954)), and increases the chance of cold spots.

Comment: "Is there any way that I can fit two bowls (or plates) in the same microwave without either one getting in the way of the other one?". Useless third tip, and borrowed 2nd tip that wasn't even explained better.  The first tip actually makes sense. So I guess 1+, could you add some more info on the first 1 of course.

Comment: How can I disable the turntable?

Comment: @Tim Most microwaves have a button to disable the automatic turntable.

Comment: Disabling the turntable leaves you with cold spots (cold spots are the reason the turntable is there in the first place).